# Existence of proper maps for compactly-supported Mayer-Vietoris

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was given the following exercise: "Let $\{U,V\}$ be an open cover of a manifold $M$. Prove that there is an exact sequence $$0\to \Omega_c^*(M)\to \Omega_c^*(U)\oplus\Omega_c^*(V)\to\Omega_c^*(U\cap V)\to 0."$$
Bott and Tu say that this can be done - $\Omega_c^*$ is a contravariant functor under proper maps. (The covariant case is given by inclusion.) My question here is how to construct the appropriate proper maps ($U\to M$, etc.) to obtain the sequence above. In the covariant case, extension by zero is the obvious choice; there does not appear to be such an obvious choice here.

Comment: Did you try a partition of unity subordinate to the cover?

Comment: I thought about it, but I'm not convinced that the maps in a partition of unity are proper.

Answer (score 1):

1. for an *open* cover $U\cup V=M$, instead of sequence mentioned obove we can define a short exact sequence
   $$0\to \Omega_c^*(U\cap V) \to \Omega_c^*(U)\oplus\Omega_c^*(V)\to \Omega_c^*(M) \to 0$$
   (as [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology_with_compact_support) recommends) where the morphisms are defined as extension by zero.
2. the map $\Omega_c^*(M)\to \Omega_c^*(U)$ can be constructed for *closed* inclusion $U\to M$, and you can easily get the desired sequence in that case.
3. for compact $M$ and an open cover $U\cup V=M$ there is no exact sequence 
   $$0\to \Omega_c^*(M)\to \Omega_c^*(U)\oplus\Omega_c^*(V)\to\Omega_c^*(U\cap V)\to 0.$$
   suppose, there is such a sequence. but if $U$ and $V$ are path-connected, we have $H^0_c(U)=H^0_c(V)=0$, therefore the part
   $$0\to H^0_c(M)\to H^0_c(U)\oplus H^0_c(V)$$
   of the long exact sequence of cohomology cannot be exact.